# Prevenir agrupamento de sessions PHP

Tags: php, session

Tenho um sistema em PHP que utiliza sessions para armazenar os itens, notei recentemente que quando o usuário abre simultaneamente 2 abas do navegador ao concluir o pedido o sistema agrupa ou entende que a session seja uma só, qual a melhor forma para que o sistema trate como sessions independentes?

Comment: mas a session é realmente uma só, você precisa gerar a página usando as variáveis POST que não são possíveis de serem duplicadas entre abas.